# How can I get an overview of a users ownership and usage?

Tags: reporting, user-record

I am trying to get an overall view of a users ownership in SF.

e.g. - How many accounts/leads/opptys a certain user has. I wanted to use rollup summary, but can't.

In the user's page, all I see is data usage. I want to know by numbers. For each user how many records it owns.

Any ideas?

I tried to have a dashboard, that will show me both leads and accounts by user name. The filter that is added only have Account Owner (e.g.: lead is NOT filtered)

[image]

In the compatible field (as Eyescream suggested) the fields are limited, and do not contain all the possible values (e.g.: lead owner is missing)

[image]

Comment: I think normal reporting will solve this .You want on detail page?

Comment: Edit the dashboard and look at the bottom of the Leads-related component. You should be able to select a "compatible field" for the filter and point it to Lead Owner

Comment: @eyescream thanks, lead-owner is missing from that list

Comment: Weird. Must be the "ooh, owner can be user or queue, we can't be sure where it points to" stupid thing... You could have a workaround by keeping OwnerId in sync with some custom Lookup(User) field... But I've upvoted the answer, seems very clean :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For "normal" data types, such as accounts and contacts, you can view a user's usage by viewing their detail page and clicking on "[View]" in the "Usage" field. This will give you a storage calculation of a user's data by data type.

Here is sample data from one of my Developer Edition accounts:

```
Record Type         Record Count    Storage Usage   Percent
Leads               39              78 KB           16%
Contacts            38              76 KB           16%
Opportunities       37              74 KB           15%
Cases               28              56 KB           11%
Accounts            28              56 KB           11%
Campaigns           4               32 KB           7%
Tasks               15              30 KB           6%
Events              11              22 KB           5%
Solutions           10              20 KB           4%
Bugs                5               10 KB           2%
Features            3               6 KB            1%
Comments            2               4 KB            1%
Demo                2               4 KB            1%
Development Times   2               4 KB            1%
Milestones          2               4 KB            1%
Attachment Reports  2               4 KB            1%
Settings            1               2 KB            0%
Projects            1               2 KB            0%
Notes               1               2 KB            0%
Carriers            1               2 KB            0%
Tests               0               0 B             0%
```

Note that `Percent` may not total 100% due to rounding, and `Storage Usage` will be rounded when the values are large (e.g. MB or GB). Also, the `Percent` isn't relative to the entire database's capacity or the total data space used, but simply a percent of that user's data usage (e.g. if 50% of the data is in tasks, and the user owns 100,000 records, then ~50,000 records are tasks). This statistic allows administrators to determine where the bulk of a user's data lies.

`Data Usage` is synoymous with "records owned", since the owner of the record is said to be the user that the `Data Usage` is associated with. Changing the ownership of a record will also change that user's `Data Usage` statistic by the same amount. These values are indexed, so there is often some delay between when the records are created, transferred, or deleted, and when they will actually appear in the user's `Data Usage` statistic.

Some data types do not have an owner and will only appear in the organization's usage statistics. Other records aren't counted here, such as `AccountShare` records, and are considered metadata. Detail records in a custom master-detail relationship assume that the owner of the master record also owns the children, and this will be reflected in the `Data Usage` statistic. Finally, records in the Recycle Bin are not counted.

Comment: If that's the only way than... But having that in a DB would be awesome, as you can drill to the objects etc..

Comment: I agree it would be nice. Maybe I'll write a Visualforce page for that.